# How to make a path for gulp file in project's directory in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, package.json

So I have a directory "node", where I run a lot of different projects, there are 2 directories, one is "examples", that provide some modules, and "projects", where I combine them to smth good. And so, in one of projects I started to use gulp, but, all package.json "scripts" I saw was like 

`test : 'gulp'`

and etc, and in my case it doses not see my one.
`node
 |
 +-- examples
 +-- projects
     |
     +-- 1
     +-- 2
         |
         +--gulpfile.js`

What I can do, to set up my package.json to see the gulp file inside the "2" directory?

I tried to set up a new package.json inside "2", but it makes node_modules download one more, and that's actually bad, however, it works, so there is no problem with gulp file.

I expect that gulpfile.js inside 2 will be found without new package json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplest way is to specify the gulpfile when you run gulp. Assuming you run from the `node` directory:

```
gulp --gulpfile=projects/2/gulpfile.js
```

Gulp also supports a `.gulp.json` CLI configuration file where you can specify that command line flag so you don't have to repeat it every time you run it. Check [the documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli) for more info.

Comment: For first time it was sooo slow, but seems to be a solution. Thank you very much!